# kubectl "error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)" using kubectx, while no error if used the same config directly

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am encountering a weird behavior when i try to configure several KUBECONFIG environment entries concatenated with `:` such in the example here :

```sh
export KUBECONFIG=/Users/user/Work/company/project/setup/secrets/dev-qz/users/admin.conf:/Users/user/Work/company/project/setup/secrets/dev-wer/users/admin.conf:/Users/user/Work/company/project/setup/secrets/test-wer/users/admin.conf:/Users/user/Work/company/project/setup/secrets/test/users/admin.conf:/Users/user/Work/company/project/setup/secrets/dev-jg/users/admin.conf:/Users/user/Work/company/project/setup/secrets/preprod/users/admin.conf:/Users/user/Work/company/project/setup/secrets/dev/users/admin.conf:/Users/user/Work/company/project/setup/secrets/dev-fxc/users/admin.conf:/Users/user/Work/company/project/setup/secrets/cluster-setup/users/admin.conf:/Users/user/Work/company/project/setup/secrets/test-fxc/users/admin.conf:/Users/user/Work/company/project/setup/secrets/test-jg/users/admin.conf:/Users/user/Work/company/project/setup/secrets/test-qz/users/admin.conf
```

This is what is happening: if i choose with `kubectx` the cluster (not every cluster from the list, but just any), when i try `kubectl get po` i receive : `error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)` . 
But, if try to reach the same cluster passing it directly to the kubectl command with `--kubeconfig=<path to the config>` it works.
I am pretty struggling with this and just wanna know if anyone else is facing this kind of issues as well and how have solved it

Comment: I don't think `kubectx` is involved here. This was happening to me with plain `kubectl use-context` while having several kubeconfigs loaded in the `KUBECONFIG` variable. Not having `kubectx` installed at all.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually i found the problem. The flatten command that suggested to me @mario, helped me to debug better the situation.

Basically, the `in memory` or `in file` merge, makes what it supposed to do: create a kubeconfig with all uniq parameters of each kubeconfig files. This works perfectly unless on or more kubeconfig has the same labels that identify the same component. In this case the `last` in order wins. So if you have the following example:

```sh
grep -Rn 'name: kubernetes-admin$' infra/secrets/*/users/admin.conf
infra/secrets/cluster1/users/admin.conf:16:- name: kubernetes-admin
infra/secrets/cluster2/users/admin.conf:17:- name: kubernetes-admin
infra/secrets/cluster3/users/admin.conf:16:- name: kubernetes-admin
```

`cluster1` and `cluster2` won't work, while `cluster3` will work perfectly, incidentally due to the order.
The solution to this problem is to avoid non uniq fields, by renaming the label that identifies the user (for the example above). Once is done this change, everything will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Bernard. This doesn't look like anything specific to `kubectx` as it is just a **bash script, which under the hood uses `kubectl` binary**. You can see its code [here](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx/blob/master/kubectx). I guess that it will also fail in `kubectl` if you don't provide the

> But, if try to reach the same cluster passing it directly to the
>   kubectl command with --kubeconfig= it works.

There is a bit of inconsistency in the way you're testing it as you don't provide the specific `kubeconfig` file to both commands. When you use `kubectx` it relies on your multiple in-memory merged `kubeconfig` files and you compare it with working `kubectl` example in which you directly specify the `kubeconfig` file that should be used. To make this comparison consistent you should also use `kubectx` with this particular `kubeconfig` file. And what happens if you run `kubectl` command without specifying `--kubeconfig=<path to the config>` ? I guess you get similar error to the one you get when running `kubectx`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

There is a really good [article](https://ahmet.im/blog/mastering-kubeconfig/) written by Ahmet Alp Balkan - `kubectx` author, which nicely explains how you can work with multiple `kubeconfig` files. As you can read in the [article](https://ahmet.im/blog/mastering-kubeconfig/):

> #### Tip 2: Using multiple kubeconfigs at once
>
> Sometimes you have a bunch of small kubeconfig files (e.g. one per
>   cluster) but you want to use them all at once, with tools like 
>   `kubectl`  or  [`kubectx`](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx)  that
>   work with multiple contexts at once.
>
> To do that, you need a “merged” kubeconfig file. Tip #3 explains how
>   you can merge the kubeconfigs into a single file, but you can also
>   merge them in-memory.
>
> By specifying multiple files in  `KUBECONFIG`  environment variable,
>   you can temporarily stitch kubeconfig files together and use them all
>   in kubectl.
>
> ```
> export KUBECONFIG=file1:file2
> kubectl get pods --context=cluster-1
> kubectl get pods --context=cluster-2
> ```
>
> #### Tip 3: Merging kubeconfig files
>
> Since kubeconfig files are structured YAML files, you can't just
>   append them to get one big kubeconfig file, but kubectl can help you
>   merge these files:
>
> ```
> KUBECONFIG=file1:file2:file3 kubectl config view --merge --flatten > out.txt
> ```

## Possible solutions:

1. Try to merge your multiple `kubeconfig` files to a single one like in the example above to see if it's possibly problem only with in-memory merge:

   KUBECONFIG=file1:file2:file3 kubectl config view --merge --flatten > out.txt
2. Review all your `kubeconfigs` and test them individually just to make sure if they're working properly when specified in `KUBECONFIG` env variable separately. There might be some error in one of them which causes the issue.

Comment: thank you @mario, i was not blaming kubectx for the problem, i was just explaining the behaviour in order to explain in which circumstances it was happening. I am sure that kubectx is not the problem. ```And what happens if you run kubectl command without specifying --kubeconfig=<path to the config> ? I guess you get similar error to the one you get when running kubectx. Please correct me if I'm wrong.``` Unfortunately trying the test you suggested, the behaviour is that it's working (same behaviour of passing --kubeconfig)

Comment: So, excluding  an error of one of the configs (i tried exported one by one, switching to it with kubectx and everything is working fine), is there a way to avoid to merge all them to a file? This is pretty uncomfortable to use because i should have everytime that i add a cluster, to regenerate a file and point to it, while,using the KUBECONFIG=file1:file2:.......:fileN, is massively usable because it doesn't need any other operation on top of the concatenation of the configs in the env var declaration.

Comment: Update: even using the option given above `KUBECONFIG=file1:file2:file3 kubectl config view --merge --flatten > out.txt` and then switching to the clusters, i obtain the same result i was obtaining concatenating all the config files in the env var: some work, others not, and exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, @lzecca. So it's really strange... it looks like there are some issues with merging `kubeconfigs` in general, no matter if in-memory or to a single file. Yes, it's totally understandable that you may not want to merge everything to a single file, but I was just wondering if it can make a difference, but it looks like the problem is located somewhere else. Btw. what is your kubernetes version ? Actually more important seems to be here client version.

Comment: One more thing that comes to my mind... You can run `kubectl config view --flatten` and try to review your output config if there is anything missing, broken etc. Unfortunately it isn't possible to easily reproduce your particular case as you're using your specific configs and they may differ quite a lot from those of mine.